# Source files added as links do not open in Windows 8 App project if they have been added to another project as well

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, code-sharing

I'm trying to share code over several platforms by adding the source as a link into each project. If, for example, I add the same source file as a link in a Windows 8 Store App project and a Windows Phone 8 project, no matter which link I click (in either project) the file will open in the Windows Phone project, so the IntelliSense will only suggest the relevant Phone namespaces. If the linked file has only been added to the Windows 8 project it works just fine.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer as I was typing this. The problem was with VSCommands, disabling Smart Linked File Navigation under IDE Enhancements->Solution Explorer in the VSCommands options page fixed it. Just thought I'd post this in case someone else ran into the same issue.